# Xcode 7 linker error with architecture x86_64 for libcrypto.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Please refer the following screenshot:

[image]

I am using xcode 7.1.1 and OSX 10.11

I am not able to build app due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check following things:

1. You have add all frameworks properly in your app(from build phases). Sometimes google maps like framework which have dependency over some other frameworks, if they not added then they gives such error. So, Please check all dependent frameworks should also need to be included.
2. Check `Framework search paths`, If you are using any other framework apart from system's own framework, then its path should be added here.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to link-in a version of the library built for OSX, not iOS.

The only solution is to provide a version of the library built for iOS.